# Pushing music from iphone to ITunes

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, itunes

I spilled water on My macbook-pro 2015 Retina and it is out of order.

It was my daily machine and I used it to synch my iphone.

I have an old MacPro.  I was wondering is there anyway I can push data from my iphone into the MacPro.  I am mostly interested in my music.  Is there a software out there that does this type iphone to computer synch.

---

Some background Info:

- Display is dead.
- I had encrypted the hard-drive on the macbook.  And I had disallowed remote access to the machine. Is there a way I can ssh into the laptop?
- I cannot engage voice-over...I thought if I could engage voice over then that would be enough for me to navigate and enable remoting then I can transfter the files from the macbook.
- Luckily everything is backed up except my music...I just don't want to rescan and organize all my music again.

Comment: Are you sure the drives dead? Just because the computer is dead doesn’t mean the drive is dead.

Comment: @Josh - The drive is probably not dead, but I do not have a way to access it.  It is encrypted and I cannot remote into the box.

Comment: Can you open the machine?

Comment: You can convert the internal SATA drive to an external USB drive.

Comment: I was able to remove the M2 drive.  Now I got to figure out a way to connect it to my ooooold macpro...probably using usb as you suggested.  I'll update the thread later.

Comment: Please **be careful**. Drives are very delicate.